# How Do I Access localHost From VMware

Tags: html, networking, virtualization, vmware, virtual-machine

I've created a new WinXP vitual machine on my win7 using VMware player. The VM is using NAT to share the host's Internet connection and when i put `http://192.168.163.2/` in IE on VM, i can easily access the localhost on the win7.

It's fine to test sites for cross browser compatibility but when i'm going to test my wordpress blog on VM it doesn't load images. I think to solve the problem i need to access wordpress using `http://localhost/wordpress` NOT `http://192.168.174.2/wordpress`.

I've added an entry to the Windows hosts file, which is located at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, to map the IP address to a (virtual) server name but it doesn't work:

```
192.168.163.2    localhost
```

Then i tried this and it works but still doesn't load images:

```
192.168.163.2    test.localhost
```

What should i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In order to access your Windows XP machine from your Windows 7 you will need to set your network adapter as `Bridged` once you do that your Windows XP machine is considered another device on your network.

So your IP Address would be something like 192.168.0.10 as an example, this way you can access it from your Windows 7 Machine.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to access the localhost on win7 from winXP.

Comment: Yes with the bridged network setting you can also do that

Comment: To access localhost like so you would have to setup a host entry on your VM where you link localhost to the IP of the host computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think localhost will work for this - it generally is exactly that - the local machine. For going from your XP VM to your Win7 IIS page use http://(win7machinename)/wordpress or http://(yourWin7IP)/wordpress. Note that there is lots of stuff that can get in the way here. Your Win7 IIS instance is going to treat the connection from the VM just like a connection attempt from any other outside machine so your website settings and firewall settings have to allow that connection.

Answer (score 0):

How to open the localhost development server in the operating system installed in the VMware subsystem

https://gist.github.com/artemsites/e549ef93e0e87b6b8dae40a8a1b685f3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).