# How Do I Access localHost From VMware when even the computer isn't accessible from the network

Tags: vmware, localhost

There are several threads regarding accessing host's localhost from a guest OS. None attracts my specific problem, therefor IMHO this question isn't a duplication.

I did follow all the steps appear on other threads. 
My default gateway is 192.0.0.1. Pinging to it is positive, opening this url in browser brings me to the router login page. Adding my localhost port brings a 502 http error .

I'm running my VM in bridged mode, without "replicating physical network connection state"

I tested the traffic using fiddler, and he responded that "No connections could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

I disabled firewall in both sides. I also disabled proxy in IE browser, and ran ipconfig /release & /renew.

Than I thought- lets try accessing my pc from my vmware. I see it in my network but the folder isn't accessible. Other yes. Other people here in my job can access my pc, without any problems.

I have no idea where more to go or to try. Hope someone here might be able to help me.
Thank you!

Other posts regarding this matter:

- http://www.rowlando.com/blog/2009/01/11/reaching-localhost-from-vmware-virtual-machines-on-a-mac/
- [How Do I Access localHost From VMware](https://superuser.com/questions/307001/how-do-i-access-localhost-from-vmware)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion

Comment: what is your host machine's ip address ?

Comment: Do you have a web server running on the host machine in the first place?

Comment: @Shakehar- my host IPv4 default gateway is 172.0.0.1.

Comment: @Chris- Yes. My VS2010 is running at localhost:40365.

Comment: I forgot mentioning that I'm running my VM in bridged mode, without "replicating physical network connection state"

Comment: `Resolved!` **The issue been with my local IIS**. I ran the virtual VS2010 and not the installed local one. He blocked calls from my vmware. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in bridged mode, your guest won't be on the same IP as your host.  They will each have separate IP addresses.  Localhost will only refer to the machine it is being called on.

Post ipconfig /all or ifconfig from both guest and host so we can see what we're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your reply.

I have uploaded print screens of the two ipconfigs, cause pasting them here isn't that readable and with bad text format.

1. The Vmware [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/30sfrj4.jpg)

2. My host ipconfig [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/2v0j3ts.png)

Comment: So it looks like you should be able to access each server at 172.0.0.22 and 172.0.0.29, respectively.  The 192. network is not shared between both machines.

Comment: Hi @jim & thanks for your response. It doesn't work for me. I'm pinging successfully 172.0.0.22, but in the browser the page doesn't load. (I've tried to replace the ip with localhost in the host file, with no success). I opened Fiddler and got error 502 from the browser.

Comment: Fiddler also gives this error - [Fiddler] The socket connection to 172.0.0.22 failed. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond .

Comment: If fiddler is the issue - This checkbox is checked for me http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/01/29/fiddler-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx

Comment: `Resolved!` **The issue been with my local IIS**. I ran the virtual VS2010 and not the installed local one. He blocked calls from my vmware. Thanks for the help.